# Cygwin: Adding new path with space in it to the path variable does not work with cygwin

Tags: cygwin, environment-variables

When I add a new path to the path variable in control panel->system->advanced->environment variables->system variables->path(edit) this path does not work in cygwin.

For example adding: ";C:\Program Files\Something" to the path variable cygwin does not find the executables due to the space character.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by running the cygwin setup, but is there a simpler way of fixing this?